# Relationship between eigenvector/values and QR decomposition

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In the last two weeks I've been studying both the characteristic vector/roots of matrices and the QR decomposition. However, I felt that there were many similarities between the two processes and so I'm wondering is there any relationship between eigenvectors/values and QR decompositions or have I just got this completely wrong?

The reason I ask is that I was doing some algebra on the following symmetric matrix $A$,
\begin{bmatrix}
       2 & 1 \\
       1 & 2 \\
     \end{bmatrix}
where the spectral decomposition, $A = C \Lambda C'$ is,

$\begin{bmatrix}
       2 & 1 \\
       1 & 2 \\
     \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & -1 \\
  1 & 1 \\
 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  3 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 \\
 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 1 \\
  -1 & 1 \\
 \end{bmatrix}$.

Now, the orthogonal version of $Q$ (not the **orthonormal** version because I haven't made it into units yet) in the $QR$ decomposition of $A$ is 
\begin{bmatrix}
       2 & -1 \\
       1 & 2 \\
     \end{bmatrix}
Now if I have calculated this correctly, that matrix is the product of $A_{ij}$ and $C_{ij}$ so I just wondering is this by chance or will this always happen? Or is what I'm seeing even a real thing?

Answer (score 2):

QR Decomposition provides a way to calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors.  See "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm".

Additionally, since $Q$ is orthogonal, it has determinant equal to $\pm 1$, so that once you've found the $QR$ decomposition, you can easily find the product of the eigenvalues (determinant of $A=QR$ is the product of the eigenvalues) by multiplying the elements in the diagonal on $R$.  Not widely useful, but knowing the $QR$ decomposition makes this easier.

Comment: I didn't know about the eigenvalue/diagonal of $R$ relationship so thanks for bringing that up. I think $QR$ algorithms are a bit above my intellectual pay grade so I've edited the question to address what I really wanted to know! Thanks